# TS Type guard for Array.some

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```js
import {  UseQueryResult } from "@tanstack/react-query"

export function combine(
    results: [
        UseQueryResult<{
            user: { id: string }
        }>,
        UseQueryResult<{
            companies: [{ id: string }]
        }>,
    ],
) {
    const isSuccess = results.every(result => result.isSuccess)

    function getValue() {
        // I want to replace this condition with
        // if (isSuccess) {
        if (results[0].isSuccess && results[1].isSuccess) {
            const [
                {
                    data: { user },
                },
                {
                    data: { companies },
                },
            ] = results

            return { companies, user }
        }

        return void 0
    }

    return {
        isSuccess,
        value: getValue(),
    }
}
```

In the `getValue` function I use this condition

`results[0].isSuccess && results[1].isSuccess`

I want to replace this

`if (isSuccess) {`

but in this case, `typescript` does not understand that there is an object inside, and not `undefined`. It seems I need to write `type-guard` to define `isSuccess` but I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible ATM, mostly because of [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498) : typescript has no way to annotate a function as immediately-invoked.